# Complex SQL Query - Popular Content

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

So, I'm writing a query to select data from the database, and display it in an order of popularity. I understand that this is simple enough to do if it were just ordering it through something such as `ORDER BY numLikes DESC` or something, but in this case, I am wanting to order the content by `numLikes` and through `datePosted`.

How would I sort the content in a way that it displays the top content from today's date? If it sorted purely through `numLikes`, The top content would float to the top and stay there. I want this content to be sorted through a daily basis. This is to allow for a system where the user can choose popular posts from the past day, past week, past month, and all time top posts.

Could this be done through a single SQL query? Would an SQL multi-query have to be done? Is SQL powerful enough to do this, or is PHP required to play a role?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this with order by. I can't really offer a suggestion because there is nothing to work with. No tables, no data, no business rules. What defines a "top post"? For "today" it should be pretty simple. where datePosted > dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) order by numLikes. You could use the same date range logic for any of the other periods.

Comment: Please add example of your data and what you expect as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to sort on `datePosted` first and then by `numLikes`. Something on the following lines:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY datePosted, numLikes DESC
```

If you want top post between a particular range, you can do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tableName 
WHERE datePosted BETWEEN [MinDate] AND [MaxDate]
ORDER BY datePosted, numLikes DESC
```

Replace [MinDate] and [MaxDate] with the dates you need, e.g. for the past week, they would be something like April-14 and April-20.

Comment: Your query caused the data to be sorted by date, and had no effect on the `numLikes`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY datePosted DESC, numLikes DESC`
added another DESC, to put today on top...